# Asking user to fill slots in Rasa Chatbot

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I am struggling to create a dialogue structure when I need to ask the user to fill the slots.

Consider the following interaction.

```
User: What is the scientific name of Eagles?
Bot: There are 3 eagles. Choose one.

 - greater spotted eagle
 - tawny eagle
 - indian spotted eagle

User: tawny eagle
Bot: Scientific name of Tawny Eagle is Clanga clanga
```

Here's my `Stories.md` file if there's only one value.

```
## Story1
* Scientific_name{'common_name': 'eagles'}
  - action_sci_name
```

And my `action.py`

```
class ActionSciName(Action):
    def name(self):
        return "action_sci_name"

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
         # below line gives 'Eagles`
         name = tracker.latest_message['entities'][0]['value']
         ## I fetch the value from DB for eagles if they are more than 1
         ## More code here
         response = """There are 3 eagles. Choose one 
                       1. greater spotted eagle
                       2. tawny eagle
                       3. indian spotted eagle"""

         dispatcher.utter_message(response)
         return []
```

The above file does 1st part fine. But I'm stuck on next where the user needs to enter the value between those 3.

Intents:

- Scientific_name
- Common_name

Entities:

- common_name
- sci_name

I have seen many articles and blogs but they are very basic. They use `slots` but users enter the value in the 1st line itself.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I see that your are facing issues with single word/phrase replies from user.
Please refer my answer here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55016421/8169091
let me know how it works.

Comment: that was helpful ...appending the string/label with user input.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [forms](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/forms/) in Rasa could help you. With forms you can validate the input and specify which slots have to be filled by the user.