# How to define entities with intent independent in RASA NLU?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot, rasa-nlu, named-entity-extraction

I am working in RASA NLU to extract intents and entities in Arabic language, and I have my own entities such as (places, org, and people) and i want to add these entities without any intent. 
I just want to add them as an entities and their type.
How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want NLU to extract entities without an intent or just have default (predefined) entities for every intent?

Comment: I want to extract entities without an intent.

Comment: if you want nlu to understand your single word entities, you may try this workaround approach explained in my answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55016421/8169091

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using .md or .json as training data file? I cannot think of a solution to pass an entity in markdown format without defining an intent. But in json format you may pass a text without defining an intent by simply not writing a value for the dictionary key "intent". See example below.
The documentation https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/dataformat/ says that intent is an optional field, so it should work.

`{
  "text": "show me chinese restaurants",
  "intent": ,
  "entities": [
    {
      "start": 8,
      "end": 15,
      "value": "chinese",
      "entity": "cuisine"
    }
  ]
}`

I would try leaving the value of "intent" completely empty, insert None or Null.